# What is the name of these hooks?

Tags: hanging

I made these hooks by myself using wires (galvanized steel wire) but I need to know if such hooks have a name and if they can be found anywhere to buy.

The first hook looks similar with [shower curtain hooks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081N3GJ76) (which are bigger though)

The second hook is like the first but longer

The third hook has quite an explicit shape yet it was quite useful for hanging a [coat rack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_rack)

[image]

[image]

---

############################

[image]

### [image]

############################

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've provided some general information in an Answer related to hooks that resemble yours.  If you could describe the task for these hooks better answers might be possible especially the third picture , I can't tell what you are doing with that one.

Comment: Thanks, the first two hooks are for hanging a shower shelf, the third is for hanging a coat rack. I had to make all these hooks in order to be able to use wall mounted screws that were already installed. So I didn't have to make holes and to install new screws in the wall

Comment: The top hook looks like a monkey link which was used to repair a broken cross chain on tire chains for use on snow and ice covered roads.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you did things!  Using wire to adapt pre-existing bits of hardware to a situation is great.  You can buy shiny gold wire, colorful plastic coated wire, stiff wire, whatever you want.  For the coat rack since you are mounting hardware to the back of something that will be hung on the wall, you would want to look at heavy duty picture frame hardware.

Comment: I would call them "bespoke, bent-wire hooks suitable for purpose".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks are usually named for their shape (eg L, C, S) or their use (curtain, fish, picture).   I've shown some common hooks below that might be useful as substitutes for your first two examples.

A good way to be educated on what various bits of hardware are called is to go to a good local hardware store where they have nice displays of these things.   Usually there are two displays: one is for specialized hardware for vehicle towing, and the other is for more general construction and project hardware.  I learned a lot by studying those displays.  It's better than doing it on line because you can pick the things up, play with them, get a feel for what they may or may not be capable of.

Here are a few examples that resemble some of your photos, and may be useful.

[image] Bow Shackle

[image] Quick Link

[image] Carabiner

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

S hooks (various combinations of open or closed, long or short, twisted)

Perhaps what you're trying to do in the third picture resembles a D Ring Hook (eg on the back of a picture frame)

[image] D Ring Hook

or perhaps you mean something like this

[image]

Comment: Yes, there's no substitute for this: "go to a good local hardware store where they have nice displays of these things". A lot depends on the staff too, so visit different stores on non-weekend daytime hours. Reward them with purchases and words of appreciation.

Comment: I need a hook like the last S hook you posted, long and twisted, how can I find such a hook?

Comment: As for the "rocket" - shaped hook, I find it amazing that there are no such hooks already made. The shape is funny but it is really useful for hanging things on the wall

Answer (score 2):

It's really just a modified [C-hook](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+hook&tbm=isch&chips=q:c+hook,g_1:wire:8Ejbk52ugJ4%3D&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv6ZOsqZfxAhVCYK0KHRL3DzsQ4lYoB3oECAEQJg&biw=1663&bih=907).

Answer (score 1):

Hoping to answer questions from other people whose searches may bring them here, beyond the specific things in OP's photos I refer here to a great reference source for metal hardware and also gratuitous hook porn:

https://www.asano-metal.co.jp/en/download/

[image]

When I was building hoists in my garage for a ladder and a kayak I came across this amazing Japanese company that makes high-end marine hardware.  WAY too expensive for a garage ladder hoist but their catalog is stupendous and you can learn a lot from it.  I ended up on their spam list and from that I discovered this catalog.